# Listen to cancel event for file upload in firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I want to remove the selected file for upload if I reopen the file selector and hit cancel. This works fine in Chrome for the moment, but not in Firefox.

```
            <input
              type='file'
              id='uploadDocument'
              accept={ACCEPT_TYPES}
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                if (e.currentTarget.files){
                  props.documentChanged(e.currentTarget.files[0])
                }else{
                    props.fileSelectCanceled();
                    console.error('file selection cancelled');
                  }
                }
              }
            />
```

Ideally when e.currentTarget is empty, the `props.fileSelectCanceled();` will clear the current file from state.
I've looked at several similar answers here, but no any solution I can apply.

Comment: You can set the selected file in the state when the file is selected. 
When the user clicks on the file selector you can set the selected file to null using `onClick={e => e.target.value = null}`. Change handler will go like `onChange={e => this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files[0] })}` So when the file is selected onChange handler will be executed and selected file will be stored in the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clearing the state on every onClick, the file would only be assigned to state if selected. The following code did the trick:

```
           <input
              type='file'
              id='uploadDocument'
              accept={ACCEPT_TYPES}
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                  if (e.currentTarget.files){
                    props.documentChanged(e.currentTarget.files[0]);
                  }
                }
              }
              onClick={() => props.fileSelectCanceled()}
            />
```